# Jquery select onClick

Tags: jquery, select, onclick, onselect

I want to add a background overlay on my webpage to darken the website when a selectbox is opened.

This needs to be triggered when the select is opened I tried using onClick but that doesn't work. onChange only works if there is something selected other than the dfault value but this is not what I want. I want it to trigger whenever the select is clicked.

[image: See example of dimmed bg]

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, I use select2 and I found it in their documentation:

select2:close   Triggered whenever the dropdown is closed. select2:closing is fired before this and can be prevented.

select2:open    Triggered whenever the dropdown is opened. select2:opening is fired before this and can be prevented.

Select 2 code used:

```
  $('.select2').on('select2:open', function (e) {
    $('.menu-overlay').addClass('block')
  });
```

Overlay beeing the div that darkens the website.

Comment: Show some actual code if you want your answer to get upvotes.

Comment: Nothing in the question says that you're using the Select2 plugin.

Comment: Added the code I used. I was't specifically looking for code compatible with Select2 that is why I didn't mention it. That beeing said I'm still looking for an answer on how to achive this without using the Select2 plugin.